# Get registers with ptrace in arm-linux

Tags: c, linux, arm, cpu-registers, ptrace

Tried to get PC register of thread in arm linux.

There is process , process id =  120 and it has 3 threads : threads id : 121,122,123 .

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
int main()
{
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    ptrace (PTRACE_ATTACH,123,0,0);
    ptrace (PTRACE_GETREGS,123,NULL,&regs);
    printf ("0x%x",regs.pc);
}
```

When compiled in gcc - arm compiler , get error `error: storage size of 'regs' isn't known struct user_regs_struct regs`

Why this struct unknown?  how do I get registers value of thread with ptrace?

Comment: Looking at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/ptrace.h#L124 , it looks like you should use `struct pt_regs`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `sys/user.h`, like the `man` page says.

It's likely you'll find it under a different name, such as `struct user_regs`.

Comment: `user_regs_struct` seems to be x86 specific.  The `user_regs` seems to be ARM specific in some kernel versions.  Different ARM Linux may/may not have VFP so the `PTRACE_GETREGS` returns different values.  I believe that R0-R15 are always the first 16 integers returned.  You can allocate a larger array and just use the first 16 values.  CPSR is 16 and orignal R0 is 17.  Then VFP if present.